# Nested Resources- 2nd object id not being pulled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this line of code in my view:

```
<%= link_to(@a.heroes[i]['name'], edit_d3user_d3hero_path(@temp_d3user, @temp_d3hero)) %><br/>
```

and I get the following error, and I can't figure out why

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"d3heros", :d3user_id=>#<D3user id: 4, x_battleTag: "rwk-1242", x_timePLayed: nil, x_killMnstrTtl: 1014469, x_killsEliteTtl: 51552, x_lastHeroPlayed: "10692899", x_game_id: nil, created_at: "2013-01-14 13:10:35", updated_at: "2013-01-14 23:10:17">, :id=>false}
```

Changing the code manually to

```
<%= link_to(@a.heroes[i]['name'], edit_d3user_d3hero_path(@temp_d3user, 1)) %><br/>
```

works, so the problem can be isolated to the @temp_d3hero object's id not being pulled by the code.

@temp_d3hero's debug

```
--- !ruby/object:D3hero
attributes:
  id: 1
  x_name: Ziyi
  x_class: wizard
  x_id: '10692899'
  x_level: 60
  ...
```

@temp_d3user's debug

```
--- !ruby/object:D3user
attributes:
  id: 4
  x_battleTag: rwk-1242
  x_timePLayed: !!null 
  x_killMnstrTtl: 1014469
```

and finally my models

D3hero

```
class D3hero < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :x_class, :x_name, :x_level, :x_life, :x_damage, :x_id , :x_gender

  validates :x_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  belongs_to :d3user
end
```

D3user

```
class D3user < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :x_battleTag, :x_game_id, :x_killMnstrTtl, :x_killsEliteTtl, :x_lastHeroPlayed, :x_timePLayed

  has_many :d3heros
end
```

and routes.rb

```
D3gearcheck::Application.routes.draw do
  get "d3heros/new"

  get "d3users/new"

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :heroines
  resources :d3users do
    resources :d3heros
  end
  resources :d3heros
```

Any help on how to get it to work is very much appreciated.

Thanks!

UPDATE- controller

```
def resultv2
@mystring = params[:battleTag]
@mystring.gsub!("#", "-")  

@a = Covetous::Profile::Career.new @mystring
# after is interpret only if no exception before
flash.now[:success] = 'Battle Tag Lookup Successful'
@acount = @a.heroes.count

#### hack -- d3user not created. create it now. Otherwise, update now.

@d3user = D3user.find_by_x_battleTag(@mystring)
if !@d3user
  D3user.create(:x_battleTag => @mystring,
                :x_killMnstrTtl => @a.kills['monsters'],
                :x_killsEliteTtl => @a.kills['elites'],
                :x_lastHeroPlayed => @a.lastHeroPlayed) 
else
  @d3user.update_attributes(:x_battleTag => @mystring,
                           :x_killMnstrTtl => @a.kills['monsters'],
                           :x_killsEliteTtl => @a.kills['elites'],
                           :x_lastHeroPlayed => @a.lastHeroPlayed)     
end
```

Also, @temp_d3hero and @temp_d3user is isnitialized via

```
<% @temp_d3user = local_d3user?(params[:battleTag]) %>
<% @temp_d3hero = local_d3hero?(@a.heroes[i]['id']) %>
```

It is returning valid and right object too, as shown by the debug of the 2 objects above

Comment: Why are you declaring your `:d3heros` resource twice?

Comment: so that I have d3hero resource without being tied to d3users

Comment: What does your controller code look like for this action?

Comment: @Joshua Rieken - Controller code attached. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused; you have variables `@temp_d3user` and `@temp_d3hero` in your view code, but only `@d3user` in your controller code. My hunch is that you're not properly assigning `@d3hero`, but I'm not sure since your view and controller code are different.

Comment: @Joshua Rieken - Sorry the code is not cleaned up yet. temp_d3user and temp_d3hero is initialized straight from the view for convenience and as a test. The debug message shows that they are returning the correct object above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= link_to(@a.heroes[i]['name'], edit_d3user_d3hero_path(@temp_d3user, @temp_d3hero.id)) %><br/>
```

Comment: Hmm.. I tried that and got this error instead-
    
undefined method `id' for false:FalseClass